# Flutter - Error in checking internet connectivity

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have implemented the below given code to check if the user is connected to the internet or not, and if the user is not connected then display a no internet screen otherwise show the apps content. but the setState is not updating the connection status. It works fine when using on a single screen, but when I open another screen and then return to this screen again it always return internet connection as false, which is the initial value. I implemented the same code for every screen I have.

[Edit: I noticed that it only happens if i implement the same code for every screen that I have, if I implement this code on a single screen, than it works fine.]

```
bool hasInternet = false;
  late StreamSubscription internetSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    debugPrint(hasInternet.toString());
    internetSubscription =
        InternetConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen((status) {
      final hasInternet = status == InternetConnectionStatus.connected;
      setState(() => this.hasInternet = hasInternet);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    internetSubscription.cancel();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return hasInternet
        ? [App Content]
        : const NoInternetScreen();
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you check if user is connected on `build` method instead of using a listener?

Comment: @KęstutisRamulionis I tried. I wrote the code I wrote in initState() inside the build(), but I got the same result.

Comment: I think you have to have this check on the widget that will never get removed from the stack, only leaving app closed condition.

Comment: Awesome it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

The error was occuring because I used that code on every screen that my app had. I solved it by wrapping the MaterialApp's home widget.

```
MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData.dark(),
          home: hasInternet ? const MainScreen() : const NoInternetScreen(),
```